# Spring Framework : Loading multiple .xml configuration files

Tags: mysql, xml, spring

I am trying to come up with a program that loads multiple configuration .xml files in spring framework.

This is the error I have encountered:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JDBCTemplateFileLog' defined in class path resource [BeansFileLog.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
```

These are my xml files:

1. Beans-All-Modules.xml

   `<import resource="BeansJDBC.xml" />
     <import resource="BeansFileLog.xml" />
     <import resource="BeansCFAE.xml" />`
2. BeansJDBC.xml

   `<bean id="dataSource" 
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
         <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST"/>
         <property name="username" value="root"/>
         <property name="password" value="password"/>
   </bean>`
3. BeansFileLog.xml

   ```
       '<bean id="JDBCTemplateFileLog" class="in.customfileaccessevent.JDBCTemplateFileLog">
           <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
       </bean>`
   ```
4. BeansCFAE.xml

   `<bean id="customFileAccessEvent" class="in.customfileaccessevent.CustomFileAccessEvent">
       <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String">
               <value>E:/HelloWorld.doc</value>
       </constructor-arg>
   </bean>`

   ```
   `<bean id="customEventHandler" class="in.customfileaccessevent.CustomFileAccessEventHandler" />

   <bean id="customFileAccessEventPublisher" class="in.customfileaccessevent.CustomFileAccessEventPublisher" />`
   ```

I have added external jar file "MysqlConnecterJ.. .jar" to the program. Still I am unable to figure out what the problem is?

The MainApp.java program is as follows:

`public class MainAppAllModules {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans-All-Module.xml");
    //ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"BeansCFAE.xml", "BeansJDBC.xml"});

            CustomFileAccessEvent ce = (CustomFileAccessEvent) context.getBean("customFileAccessEvent");
    CustomFileAccessEventPublisher cvp = 
            (CustomFileAccessEventPublisher) context.getBean("customFileAccessEventPublisher");
    cvp.publish(ce);  
    /*ConfigurableApplicationContext context1 = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("BeansJDBC.xml");*/  
    JDBCTemplateFileLog flogJDBCTemplate = (JDBCTemplateFileLog) context.getBean("JDBCTemplateFileLog");
    System.out.println("File Log Creation");
    flogJDBCTemplate.create("Sample", "Sample");



}
```

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a dataSource bean for "dataSource" to reference. Your xml files are importing fine. Try [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/) to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I went through the tutorial you referred me to. I have tried to combine two codes in my program; one is that of a custom file access event and the second one is a Spring jdbc example. I followed the instructions from the tutorial, can't seem to debug it.

Comment: After implementing the datasource part of it, do you get an error when you try to run the program?

Comment: I recoded everything from scratch. It seems to have done the trick. I tried to copy the same program files onto another package, after some edits, it worked. I found it strange, could you explain further about this issue? I also found out that the `<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">` was 2.5.xsd in my xml file. I am working with Spring 4.0

Comment: That's the version of spring, so it should be 4.0.xsd for you. If my answer answered your question, you should accept it as the accepted answer.